# Allowing custom CSS

Tags: php, css, security

I want to allow my users to insert their custom CSS into their websites.

The custom CSS file will be served to the customers website only. I will host the CSS myself and I'm thinking of serving it through a PHP script and doing the filtering there.

- What should I pay attention to while doing this?
- I should filter things, what exactly should not be included in the CSS file?

Thank you

Comment: There are a few things to concern yourself with.  One of which is that you can simply hide all of your elements on the page and replace them with some giant graphic that you probably don't want to see.  Is that an issue for you?  Other issues may arise depending on how you are including the user-supplied CSS, and what it's purpose is.  Then you also have the potential exploit of services that perform actions for GET requests, but you may not care about that.

Comment: The user supplied CSS will only be visible on his part. I think people may try to upload all kinds of malicious things including PHP and/or JS code. So what should I pay attention to?

Comment: As I said, you need to provide more detail.  Are you hosting this CSS?  Depending on how you include it, you might not have to do anything.  Show us what you are doing.

Comment: I can see close votes but no information why it has been close-voted.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this sometime ago. My approach was to create a seperate php/css document. Create a html/php page with a form on it with inputs for the user to input their styling options. Post this to the css/php script and then use the variables from the post accordingly. You would need to escape all post requests for security.

Put this within your `html` document

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />
```

Create a php/css document like so

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "#555555";
   $CDNURL = "http://cdn.blahblah.net";
?>

#header {
   background: url("<?php echo $CDNURL; ?>/images/header-bg.png") no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}   
ul#main-nav li a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Hmm yes. They could modify the colours but not the style at all. Yes seems interesting :) Thank you!

Comment: They could modify style/color etc, which ever you choose. they could rewrite your entire CSS if you let them.

Comment: As implemented here, someone could modify whatever they wanted in your CSS, include external CSS, etc.  Your line about "you would need to escape all post requests for security" should not be taken lightly.  Better in this case to actually validate the values you accept.

Comment: @Brad You would only apply the post request variables to elements that you specify within your script. Also you would run checks using regex on all entries to ensure they meet your requirements, plus escaping. This is just a basic example. When i posted it i assumed some knowledge of the developer.

Comment: @Vector, Agreed, I'm just adding notes with the hope that someone doesn't blindly copy/paste what you have without knowing what they're doing.